# How can I load a picture with alpha channel in JME?

Tags: 2d, graphics, jmonkeyengine, alpha

This code loads a picture into the game:

```
Picture mypic= new Picture("mypic");
        Texture2D tex = (Texture2D) assetManager.loadTexture("Textures/mypic.png");
        mypic.setTexture(assetManager, tex, false);
        mypic.setHeight(settings.getHeight());
        mypic.setWidth(settings.getWidth());
```

What have to be modified or add to show properly a picture with an alpha channel?

Answer (score 1):

You should change this:

```
mypic.setTexture(assetManager, tex, false);
```

to this:

```
mypic.setTexture(assetManager, tex, true);
```

to show a picture with an alpha channel.

The third parameter is `useAlpha`, which, if set to false will just render your transparent/translucent pixels as black.

Comment: It doesn't work.